# Получить описание для SAML Authentication Context Class URI

Tags: c#

Создаю `SecurityToken` с помощью `Saml2SecurityToken` следующим образом:

```
SecurityToken st = new Saml2SecurityToken(
  new Saml2Assertion(new Saml2NameIdentifier("localUser"))
  {
      Statements =
      {
          new Saml2AttributeStatement(new List<Saml2Attribute>()
          {
              new Saml2Attribute(
                  "http://identityserver.thinktecture.com/claims/identityprovider", 
                  "promProvider")
          }),
          new Saml2AuthenticationStatement(new Saml2AuthenticationContext(
              new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password"))) 
      },
      Subject = new Saml2Subject(new Saml2NameIdentifier("administrator")) { 
          SubjectConfirmations = { new Saml2SubjectConfirmation(
              new Uri("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"))}},
      SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
          new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(certificate), 
          SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, 
          SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest, 
          new SecurityKeyIdentifier() { new X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(certificate) }) 
  }, new ReadOnlyCollection<SecurityKey>(new List<SecurityKey>()), securityToken);
```

Все это используется для того, чтобы создать прокси сервиса, работающего по протоколу безопасности: `WS2007FederationHttpBinding` и работает успешно, не буду углубляться в подробности, так как суть вопроса другая. Вопрос следующий, имеются строки, которые я прописываю руками, что мне не очень нравится, а именно:

1. `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password"` - Authentication Context Class URI
2. `"urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"` - Subject Confirmation Method

Имеются ли какие-либо справочники, откуда я могу достать эти строки, к примеру перечисления или классы, в которых это хранится,  такого плана:

```
// "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"
var rsaSha256Signature = SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature;
// "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"
var sha256 = SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest;
```

Если имеются, то откуда я могу их получить?

Comment: Когда я этим занимался, я быстро обнаружил что токен проще создавать через `SecurityTokenDescriptor` и `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`. Может, там вам эти константы и не понадобятся?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, без этих констант падает исключение. Прокси сервиса создать не могу...

Comment: Брр. При чем тут исключение? Говорю же, попробуйте через SecurityTokenDescriptor создать токен.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `SecurityTokenDescriptor` не преобразуется в  `SecurityToken`. Но суть не в этом, я в вопросе писал, что суть другая. Относительно создания токена - попробовал, не подходят другие варианты. Единственное, что меня интересует, это где взять константы, которые мне *глаза режут* :)

Comment: Как - не преобразуется? А почему тогда у меня преобразуется?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не совсем понятно... прямым текстом пишет: `Cannot convert type System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor to System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50932/discussion-between-denis-bubnov-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение следующее: создавать `SecurityToken` через `SecurityTokenDescriptor` с помощью `Saml2SecurityTokenHandler`. В этом случае константы не нужны. В результате кода стало меньше и выглядеть код стал приятно:

```
var saml2SecurityTokenHandler = new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    TokenIssuerName = "production",
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity("administrator"),
    Token = new X509SecurityToken(certificate),
    SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(
        new X509AsymmetricSecurityKey(certificate),
        SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature,
        SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest,
        new SecurityKeyIdentifier() { new X509RawDataKeyIdentifierClause(certificate) })
};

var securityToken = saml2SecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
```

К решению данного вопроса пришел с помощью советов от пользователя @PavelMayorov, ему отдельное спасибо. А константы так и не нашел, если найду - дополню свой ответ.

Последовал очередному совету по поводу использования `X509SigningCredentials` вместо `SigningCredentials` и получилось то, что меня устраивает в качестве конечного результата:

```
var saml2SecurityTokenHandler = new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler();
var securityTokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
{
    TokenIssuerName = "production",
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity("administrator"),
    Token = new X509SecurityToken(certificate),
    SigningCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(certificate)
};

var securityToken = saml2SecurityTokenHandler.CreateToken(securityTokenDescriptor);
```

Все работает стабильно.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать `X509SigningCredentials` вместо `SigningCredentials`, код станет еще проще.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, хорошо, попробую немного позже, спасибо.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, замена `X509SigningCredentials` на `SigningCredentials` и вправду разгрузила код. Стало еще проще и понятнее. Спасибо за советы )